# using non prime numbers in Blum Blum Shub or Blum Micali

Tags: random-number-generator, blum-blum-shub

I would like to use Blum Blum Shub, or Blum Micali methods as random number generators only. I am not interested in their encryption capabilities. 
I was wondering, if I replaced the prime numbers with other random numbers that are not prime, how much will this affect:

1. the security of RNG
2. the randomness of the numbers generated.

Comment: "I would like to use Blum Blum Shub, or Blum Micali methods as random number generators only"  - why?  There are much better ones known...

Comment: Also, as long as the prime factors of the numbers are distinct and they are congruent to mod 4, you can consider it is just extension...

Comment: which ones are known better than Blum Blum Shub and Blum Micali? i want CSPRNG ones for cryptographical reasons.